# Сделать Dataclass объект immutable после __post_init__

Tags: python-3.x

Есть класс

```
from typing import List
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass(repr=False, eq=False, order=False)
class Models:
    path: str 
    targets: List[str] = field(default_factory=list) 
    columns: List[str] = field(default_factory=list, init=False)
```

Атрибут `columns` я определяю в `__ post_init __(self)`

```
def __post_init__(self):
    self.columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

И мне бы хотелось сделать объект класса `Models` immutable  после инициализации (пост-инициализации?)

Если прописать `@dataclass(Frozen=True)` , то теряется возможность определить атрибут в `post_init`

Можно ли прописать аналог Frozen=True, только уже после init и post_init?

Какие могут быть альтернативные варианты?

Comment: А почему бы сразу не задать значения в поле? `columns: List[str] = field(default_factory=lambda: ['a', 'b', 'c'], init=False)`

Comment: `self.columns` может быть от 100 до 3000+ и определяется в зависимости от того, что я укажу в `targets`

Comment: Поясню задачу класса `Models`. У меня есть сет (например 10000+ фичей), есть несколько таргетов (например 10). Каждый таргет обучен на каком-то подмножестве фичей сета. Я хочу указывать путь (разный путь - разные модели), указывать таргет (может 1, а может 6) и в `columns` иметь пересечение всех фичей, необходимых для всех моделей для каждого таргета

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно переопределить магический метод `__setattr__` и в нем выбрасывать исключение.

Пример:

```
from typing import List
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass(repr=False, eq=False, order=False)
class Models:
    path: str
    targets: List[str] = field(default_factory=list)
    columns: List[str] = field(default_factory=list, init=False)

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']

        self._is_post_init = True

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if hasattr(self, '_is_post_init'):
            raise Exception(f'cannot assign to field "{key}"')
        return super().__setattr__(key, value)

Models('123').columns = []
# Exception: cannot assign to field "columns"
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, думал в эту сторону, но так и не догадался самстоятельно, как это реализовать. Так же переопределю `__delattr__`